# HTML input type text pattern for SSN doesn't match

Tags: html, regex

Weird behavior I'm finding on the HTML Input type using the pattern for SSN validation:

```
<input name="employeeSSN" id="employeeSSN" placeholder="###-##-####" value="${this.employee ? this.employee.employeeSSN : ''}" type="text" maxlength="11" pattern="^(?!(000|666|9))\d{3}-(?!00)\d{2}-(?!0000)\d{4}$" class="form-control" autocomplete="new-password" required>
```

The pattern I'm using `pattern="^(?!(000|666|9))\d{3}-(?!00)\d{2}-(?!0000)\d{4}$"` should allow a number like this:
`022-55-2999`

Well it doesn't match on Chrome Version 83.0.4103.97 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Am I doing something wrong?

Following @Andran comments below I used the web site he suggested and the website return a successful match:
[image]

Comment: You can check for https://regex101.com/
It will be better if you give a pattern with a variable

Comment: I added the site you suggested picture it match, but Chrome doesn't seems to match it

Comment: try `pattern="^(?!(000|666|9))\\d{3}-(?!00)\\d{2}-(?!0000)\\d{4}$"`

Comment: this should work, because when creating a pattern using string, you need to follow the rules `\d => \\d`

Comment: It match here regex101.com  but the browser still complain that it isn't match, probably is a bug on Chrome?

Comment: No, you should use \\ d

Comment: It worked!!! Thanks @Andran

Comment: You are welcome ))